# Why is this array null?

Tags: java, arrays

Why is my petArray null?
the myArray array is fine, but idk why the petArray is null

**this is my .txt file:**

```
112|C|Fluffy|4/1/2011|Tabby|Gray|M|Y|N|N
332|D|Phydeaux|6/3/2009|Collie|White/Tan|M|N|N|N
237|C|Snagglepuss|5/13/2010|Siamese|Sable|M|Y|Y|N
165|C|Sylvester|1/12/2008|Tuxedo|Black/White|F|N|N|N
113|C|Fluffy|499/1/2011|Tabby|Gray|M|Y|N|N
333|X|Phydeaux|6/3/2009|Collie|White/Tan|M|N|N|N
238|C|Snagglepuss|5/13/2010|Siamese|Sable|M|Y|Y|N
166|C|Sylvester|1/12/2008|Tuxedo|Black/White|F|N|G|N
114|C|Fluffy|4/1/2011|Tabby|Gray|M|Y|N|N
334|D|12/4/2005|Phydeaux|Collie|White/Tan|M|N|N|N
239|C|Snagglepuss|5/13/2010|Siamese|Sable|M|Y|Y|N
167|P|Sylvester|1/12/2008|Tuxedo|Black/White|F|N|E|N
115|C|Fluffy|4/1/2011|Tabby|Gray|M|Y|
335|D|Phydeaux|6/3/2009|Collie|White/Tan|M|N|N|N
240|C|Snagglepuss|5/13/2010|Siamese|Sable|M|Y|Y|N
168|C|Sylvester|1/12/20085|Tuxedo|Black/White|F|N|N|N
```

**PetGUI.java:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
/*
* Makes a new JFrame thats makes two textareas, fills in the textareas
*  from the array and linkedlist.
*/
public class PetGUI extends JFrame{
static int number;
static String[] animalArray;
static TextArea north;
static TextArea south;
public PetGUI(TextFileInput tfi){

    int lines = 0;
    TextFileInput tfil = new TextFileInput("project4.txt");
    String rlines = tfil.readLine();
    while(rlines != null){
        lines++;
        rlines = tfil.readLine();
    }
    tfil.close();

    String [] myArray = new String[100];
    number = lines;
    animalArray = myArray;
    this.setSize(400,400);
    this.setLocation(200, 200);
    this.setTitle("Adoptable Pets");
    createFileMenu();
    createEditMenu();

    TextArea north = new TextArea(9,20);
    TextArea south = new TextArea(9,20);
    this.getContentPane().add(north,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    this.getContentPane().add(south,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    north.setEditable(false);
    south.setEditable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);

    Cat c;
    Dogs d;


    AdoptablePet [] petArray = new AdoptablePet[lines];
    for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        myArray[i] = tfi.readLine();;
    }
    tfi.close();

    for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        if(myArray[i].charAt(4) == 'C'){
            String[] r = myArray[i].split("\\|");
            if(r.length != 9){
            try{

                    throw new IllegalPetInput("Not the right length of input");
            }
            catch(IllegalPetInput a){

            }
            }
            else
                try{
                c = new Cat(Integer.parseInt(r[0]),r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4],r[5],r[6],r[7],r[8],Boolean.parseBoolean(r[9]));
                petArray[i] = c;
                }
                catch(AdoptablePetException a){
                    System.out.println("Wrong information for the cat.");
                }
        }

        if(myArray[i].charAt(4) == 'D'){
            String[] r = myArray[i].split("\\|");
            if(r.length != 9){
            try{

                    throw new IllegalPetInput("Not the right length of input");
            }
            catch(IllegalPetInput a){

            }
            }
            else
                try{
                d = new Dogs(Integer.parseInt(r[0]),r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4],r[5],r[6],r[7],r[8],Boolean.parseBoolean(r[9]));
                petArray[i] = d;

                }
            catch(AdoptablePetException a){
                System.out.println("Wrong information for the cat.");
            }
        }
    }


    LinkedList l = new LinkedList();




    for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
        System.out.println(petArray[i]);





  //Appends the north side of the texarea with all of the lines    
for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
    north.append((String) l.get(i));


}
```

Comment: Put some debug statements into  your code or use a debugger, and you'll likely see why the array is null.

Comment: While not the cause of your problem, you're doing a throw as the only line in your try with an empty catch.  Maybe you just want to have a throw in the if and nix the try/catch in those cases?

Comment: you're catching and throwing a way a bunch of exceptions, i'm betting every line fails to parse, so everything is empty.

Comment: the Array itself is not `null`. It's contents may be `null`, if you enter this `if` block: `if(r.length != 9){`. For debugging purposes, have some output in that block.

Comment: Is your array actually `null`, or is it empty? Where in your code is it `null` (or empty) when it shouldn't be?

Comment: You are not adding any data while reading the file. You need to add string which you have read from your txt file and your array, Your array is not null, I think its empty.

Comment: the array cannot be null if you are setting it as `AdoptablePet [] petArray = new AdoptablePet[lines];`

Answer (score 2):

I count 10 fields in your data, your checks say there should only be 9, then throw an exception which is caught and thrown away.

```
if(r.length != 9)
{
     try
     {
          throw new IllegalPetInput("Not the right length of input");
     }
     catch(IllegalPetInput a)
     {
         // you're throwing this away!  bad form!
     }
 }
```

later on, you look at 10 fields worth of data!

```
c = new Cat(Integer.parseInt(r[0]),r[1],r[2],r[3],
    r[4],r[5],r[6],r[7],r[8], 
    Boolean.parseBoolean(r[9])); // field number 10!
```

You're also closing your input stream after counting the lines:

```
TextFileInput tfil = new TextFileInput("project4.txt");
String rlines = tfil.readLine();
while(rlines != null){
    lines++;
    rlines = tfil.readLine();
}
tfil.close();  // stream closed!  any reads after this should hypothetically have failed!
```

you're never re-opening it, so nothing else ever works.

get rid of the array and use an ArrayList, don't read the file once to see how many rows you're going to have ahead of time.

Comment: This still wouldn't explain `petArray` being `null`. Perhaps it's just empty (length 0)?

Comment: I fixed these problems and still the array is null. Any other ideas?

Comment: instead of using an array, use an ArrayList, and add items as you go.  That way you don't have to read the file 2x (once to figure out how big the array should be)

Comment: @sans481 the TextFileInput was closed after reading how many lines there are. Then I opened a new TFI which read all the lines in again making the array myArray. myArray has all of the data in it so that is not the problem.

Comment: sans481 is close.  you're actually closing the stream.  i'm not sure why any readlines after that don't flat out throw exceptions.

Comment: and @JohnGardner I have to use a regular array, its a project for my class.

Comment: well, that's kindof sad.  But you aren't reopening your reader, so that looks to be the problem.  report a bug to your professer that their class doesn't throw exceptions if you read after the stream is closed.

Comment: IMO, tfil = new TextFileInput("project4.txt"); shud be declared before reading lines second time.

Comment: also JohnGardner i started a TFI in my main so it was still running i never used it till here:     for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        myArray[i] = tfi.readLine();;
    }
    tfi.close(); 
and i close it at the end. I changed it to start right before it is used also. runs the same exact way.

Answer (score 0):

i doubt the issue is, you already read the file to count number of lines. Again to store them in an array, you are reading them. But the cursor is already at the end of file when u read number of lines. Now when u read the strings this time, the `readline()` returns null and that may be the reason your array is null.

Answer (score 0):

Because r.length is always 10 and never 9, like your if statement conditions.  You say

```
if(r.length != 9){
            try{

                    throw new IllegalPetInput("Not the right length of input");
            }
            catch(IllegalPetInput a){

            }
```

So that if statement evaluates to true, the exception is thrown and then caught immediately (why are you doing that?)